# C# MediaCapture UnuthorizedAccessException or no supported formats after Windows Update

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, uwp, mediacapture

Every since I did an update on my Windows machine, I can no longer use the camera in my UWP application that uses the `MediaCapture` class.

Origninally, I was getting an `UnuthorizedAccessException` when trying to call the `InitializeAsync()` function but, I managed to fix this by adding the **EnableFrameServerMode** to my register (via this link: https://www.macecraft.com/fix-webcam-issues-windows-10-anniversary-update/)

However, since doing this, the `MediaFrameSource.SupportedFormats` property is empty (`MediaFrameSource.SupportedFormats.Count` is 0).

This is only occurring on my machine, colleagues with identical machines (same hardware and software), and different machines, are not experiencing this issue.

I'm currently running:

- Windows 10 Home edition
- Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134

I'm building the app with **Xamarin.Forms** using **Visual Studio version 15.9.4**.
The Target Version for the app is **Windows 10.0 Build 16299** (Min Version is the same).

Here is my code from my **ViewRenderer**:

```
var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();

MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup = null;
MediaFrameSourceInfo colorSourceInfo = null;

foreach (var sourceGroup in frameSourceGroups)
{
    foreach (var sourceInfo in sourceGroup.SourceInfos)
    {
        if (sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord
            && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color
            && sourceInfo.DeviceInformation.EnclosureLocation != null
            && sourceInfo.DeviceInformation.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front)
        {
            colorSourceInfo = sourceInfo;
            break;
        }
        colorSourceInfo = sourceInfo;
    }
    if (colorSourceInfo != null)
    {
        selectedGroup = sourceGroup;
        break;
    }
    selectedGroup = sourceGroup;
}

if (selectedGroup == null || colorSourceInfo == null) return;
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
{
    SourceGroup = selectedGroup,
    SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl,
    MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
};

try
{
    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
    return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed: " + ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

If the **EnableFrameServerMode** is not set to 0 in my registry, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. If it is:

```
MediaFrameSource colorFrameSource = null;
foreach (var keyValuePairFrameSource in _mediaCapture.FrameSources)
{
    if (keyValuePairFrameSource.Key.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(colorSourceInfo.SourceGroup.Id.ToLowerInvariant()))
    {
        colorFrameSource = keyValuePairFrameSource.Value;
    }
}

_config = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfigData();

var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource?.SupportedFormats.FirstOrDefault(format =>
    format.VideoFormat.Width == _config.CameraPreviewWidth &&
    format.VideoFormat.Height == _config.CameraPreviewHeight &&
    format.Subtype == MediaEncodingSubtypes.Nv12.ToUpper());
if (preferredFormat == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Our desired format is not supported");
    return;
}
```

`SupportedFormats` List is empty, causing our `preferredFormat` object to be null.

If I don't return when `preferredFormat` is null, and do this:

```
var _mediaFrameReader = await _mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Nv12);
_mediaFrameReader.FrameArrived += ColorFrameReader_FrameArrived;
await _mediaFrameReader.StartAsync();
```

I just get a screen with a black background where the camera frames should be.

Answer (score 0):

> This is only occurring on my machine, colleagues with identical machines (same hardware and software), and different machines, are not experiencing this issue.

I checked your code, and it is similar as [`CameraFrames`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) official code sample. I have test with **LifeCam HD-3000**, and it works well(No modify the registry). I thinks it is very likely that there is a problem with your hardware device. I think you could use other camera troubleshooting. For using camera you could also check this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view).

Comment: Yeah, I tried the CameraFrames sample, and I'm getting the same errors. My colleague just did an update to his Windows machine, and is now experiencing the same issues.

Comment: In the end, it turned out to be my anti-virus... Kind of strange that we can bypass the initial "Access denied" exception with the registry value, maybe something to keep in mind.